# Twig and cycle function iteration with foreach/PDO

Tags: twig

I have a TV guide script I wrote in Twig, and it works up to a point - the data displays properly from the PDO/MySQL, but it's the cycle function with the CSS I'm having problems with.

This is my code:

index.html (snippet from relevant part)

```
<table id="show-time-results"><tbody><tr>
{% for d in data %}
{%  i in 0..10 %}
{% set guide = ['odd', 'even'] %}
<td class="{{ cycle(guide, i) }}-item name"><a href="http://localhost/twigtest/">{{d.programme}}</a><br><em class="episode">{{ d.episode }}. </em></td><td class="info {{ cycle(guide, i) }}-item" nowrap="1" width="1%">{{d.airdate|date("F jS, Y")}} at {{d.airdate|date("g:ia")}}<br><a href="http://localhost/twigtest/">{{ d.channel }}</a></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2" class="
{{ cycle(guide, i) }}-item description"><p>{{ d.epinfo }} <a href="http://localhost/twigtest/">read more</a></p></td></tr>
     {% endfor %}
     {% endfor %}
</tbody></table>
```

and
index.php:

```
    <?php
// include and register Twig auto-loader
include 'Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

// attempt a connection
try {
  $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=tvguidetest;host=localhost', 'test', 'test');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  echo "Error: Could not connect. " . $e->getMessage();
}

// set error mode
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// attempt some queries
try {
  // execute SELECT query
  // store each row as an object
  $sql = "SELECT programme, channel, episode, epinfo, airdate FROM coronationst where airdate > NOW() ORDER BY expiration ASC LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0";
  $sth = $dbh->query($sql);
  while ($row = $sth->fetchObject()) {
    $data[] = $row;
  }

  // close connection, clean up
  unset($dbh); 

  // define template directory location
  $loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('templates');

  // initialize Twig environment
  $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array('debug' => true, 'autoescape' => false));
  $twig->addExtension(new Twig_Extension_Text());

  // load template
  $template = $twig->loadTemplate('index.html');


  // set template variables
  // render template
  echo $template->render(array (
    'data' => $data
  ));

} catch (Exception $e) {
  die ('ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
?>
```

The data displays correctly.... except it's repeating itself due to the {% for i in 0..10 %} in my code, so how can I get it to display once?

These are my records (note the table names are in d.TABLENAME in index.html above):

1 Coronation Street Channel1 10:00pm Episode 550 This is information
2 Coronation Street Channel2 6:45am  Episode 549 Information goes here
and 8 more records similar to this.

How can I fix it repeating the records when there are no duplicates? (i.e. every record is different, no content is the same, well, at least, for the episode/description/channel field)?

Comment: Perhaps you answered your question on your own but it would be kind to let us know if our answers could have helped you or even accept an answer. Just a reminder because I'm curious if my solution would work as suggested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a for loop you can access the current index - starting by 0 or 1. So in your example you can just leave out the second for loop and replace your variable "i" with my examples below.

The [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html) says

> Inside of a for loop block you can access some special variables:
>
> loop.index    The current iteration of the loop. (1 indexed)
>
> loop.index0   The current iteration of the loop. (0 indexed)

There is also an example given

```
{% for user in users %}
    {{ loop.index }} - {{ user.username }}
{% endfor %}
```

I'm sorry but your HTML/twig markup is a bit irritating. I tried to clear it up a bit.

```
<table id="show-time-results">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            {% for d in data %}
                {% set guide = ['odd', 'even'] %}
                <td class="{{ cycle(guide, i) }}-item name">
                    <a href="http://localhost/twigtest/">{{ d.programme }}</a>
                    <br>
                    <em class="episode">{{ d.episode }}.</em>
                </td>
                <td class="info {{ cycle(guide, {{ loop.index0 }} ) }}-item" nowrap="1" width="1%">
                    {{ d.airdate|date("F jS, Y") }} at {{ d.airdate|date("g:ia") }}
                    <br>
                    <a href="http://localhost/twigtest/">{{ d.channel }}</a>
                </td>
        </tr>
              <tr>
                   <td colspan="2" class="{{ cycle(guide, {{ loop.index0 }} ) }}-item description">
                       <p>{{ d.epinfo }} 
                           <a href="http://localhost/twigtest/">read more</a>
                       </p>
                   </td>
              </tr>
           {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Notice the missing 2nd `for loop` and that `{{ cycle(guide, i) }}` got replaced by `{{ cycle(guide, {{ loop.index0 }} ) }}`

Right now I'm not able to test it so if it doesn't work please be so kind and inform me before downvoting ^^

**EDIT**

This should be the working example. You need no `{{ ... }}` around `loop.index0` in this context.

```
{{ cycle(guide, loop.index0) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call `{% for %}` with an index to avoid the second loop :

```
{% for i, d in data %}
   <td class="{{ cycle(['odd', 'even'], i) }}-item name">
     (...)
   </td>
{% endfor %}
```

This of course suppose that your `data` array has numeric keys.

You can see the [documentation](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html#iterating-over-keys-and-values) for details.

If your array has no numeric keys, you can simulate numeric keys with a counter :

```
{% set i = 0 %}
{% for d in data %}
   <td class="{{ cycle(['odd', 'even'], i) }}-item name">
     (...)
   </td>
   {% set i = i + 1 %}
{% endfor %}
```